# ID reset in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, reset

I try to reset my ID in the table events but the `query("UPDATE events SET ID=".$i."WHERE ID=".$row['ID'];)` always fails. Any idea why?

```
//getting the whole table from mysql
$query="SELECT * FROM events";
$results=mysql_query($query);
$size=mysql_num_rows($results);
echo($size);

//drop the primary key 
$query="ALTER TABLE events DROP PRIMARY KEY";
if(!(mysql_query($query)))
        echo("Query1 failed");

//reset ID
for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    $query=" UPDATE events SET ID=".$i."WHERE ID=".$row['ID'];
    if(!(mysql_query($query)))
        echo("Query failed2");

}

//add primary key back to ID
$query="ALTER TABLE events ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)";
if(!(mysql_query($query)))
        echo("Query failed3");
```

Comment: print $query, and the error message

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you ever link other tables to that table, you would loose all relationships between them.

Comment: `UPDATE events SET ID=".$i."WHERE ID=".$row['ID'];` maybe put a space between the `WHERE`?

Comment: You're still using the **deprecated** mysql extension of PHP. It's highly recommended to **migrate to MySQLi or PDO**. I recommend PDO because it has a better Integration of **Prepared Statements**.

Comment: @charlotteDunois i'll probably give it a try.  I am using deprecated mysql as i wanted to practise what i've learnt at the Uni so far. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at least add a space before `WHERE`

```
$query=" UPDATE events SET ID=".$i." WHERE ID=".$row['ID'];
```

Comment: and if u wrap your statement in double qutoes the variables don't need to be wrapped as well. you could simply write: `$query = "UPDATE events SET ID=$i WHERE ID=$row['ID']";`

Comment: *You* should at least add a `Y` and an `o` before writing `u`.